# Parsing an email address (FROM or TO) with name - not necessarily rfc 2822 compliant

Tags: php, ruby, regex, sed

I have an email field that may be formatted in a few different ways.

1. `hello@world.com`
2. `"hello world" <hello@world.com>`
3. `hello world <hello@world.com>`

I would like to capture both the hello world string (if it's there) *and* the email address (if it's there). I have a regular expression that almost works, but it doesn't quite.

```
sed -r  's/"?([^"]+)*"?\s<?([^>]+@[^>]+)>?/["\1","\2"]/' <<< 'Hello World <helloworld@gmail.com>'
```

Please help?

Comment: I changed my answer, please try the my regex if it is doing what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:

This should do what you want:

```
^(?:"?([^@"]+)"?\s)?<?([^>]+@[^>]+)>?$
```

This will store the first part, if there is one, into the first capturing group and the email address int o the second group.

Answer (score 2):

The regex looks not quite right. Anyway, the "Backtrack limit was exhausted" error occurs during executing this regex (you can check it with the preg_last_error function) so you can increase backtrack limit to make it work:

```
 ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit', 1000000);
 var_dump(preg_replace('~"?([^"]+)*"?\s<?([^>]+@[^>]+)>?~', '["$1","$2"]', 'hello@world.com'));
```

outputs:

```
 string(15) "hello@world.com"
```

Comment: So how should I modify the regex?

Comment: You're absolutely right about the backtrack limit... good call on that.  The regex still must be improved though

Answer (score 1):

Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -e 'p gets.scan(/"?([^"]+)*"?\s<?([^>]+@[^>]+)>?/)' <<< '"Hello World" <helloworld@gmail.com>'
[["Hello World", "helloworld@gmail.com"]]
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for help to modify it so that it works with the unquoted string Hello World, as well as just an email address, with or without enclosing angle brackets